# On onblur event ajax get calles but it not returning to the original page

Tags: php

In my code the `onblur` event ajax method gets called in that it goes to `ajaxcarmake.php`. It executes the logic correctly but it does not come back to the `addcarmake.php` page. It also doesn't show me the alert message inside success: 
plz give me the answer what i did wrong.

**addcarmake.php**

```
<form name="addcategoryfrm" id="addcategoryfrm" action="addcarmake1-process.php" method="GET">
    <div style="width:100%;height:auto;float:left;margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="txttitle">Car Make Name </div>
        <div class="txtinputouter1">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="categoryname" onblur="check_carmake(this);"/>
        </div>
    </div>       
    <div style="width:100%;height:auto;float:left;margin-top:10px;">

        <div class="txtinputouter1" style="padding-left:30%;padding-top:40px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="demo"></div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
function check_carmake(name) {
  $name = name.value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajaxaddcarmake.php',
    data: {
      $name: $name
    },
    success: function(result) {
      if (result == 1) {
        alert("Car make name already present");
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

**ajaxaddcarmake.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username1'])) {
    include("../config/database.php");
    $name = $_GET['$name'];
    $query = "select * from  add_car_make where name='$name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $query;
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows > 0) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "*..It executes the logic correctly..*" How You Knew ??

Comment: i saw it in debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things that we have missed .

**script**

script should like this .

data should send like this

```
data: {
      name: $name
    },

not 

data: {
      $name: $name
    },
```

we were passing '$' in the variable.

```
<script>
function check_carmake(name) {
  $name = name.value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajaxaddcarmake.php',
    data: {
      name: $name
    },
    success: function(result) {
      if (result == 1) {
        alert("Car make name already present");
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

**ajaxaddcarmake.php**

Also in this php script , we have small changes.

we have to get variable like this
 $name = $_GET['name']; // remove '$' not  $name = $_GET['$name'];

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username1'])) {
    include("../config/database.php");
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $query = "select * from  add_car_make where name='$name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $query;
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows > 0) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: i did the changes ,still it doesnt show mi alert message

Comment: Can you please use this code?
<script>
function check_carmake(name) {
  $name = name.value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajaxaddcarmake.php',
    data: {
      name: $name
    },
    success: function(result) {
      if (result == 1) {
        alert("Car make name already present");
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  });
}
</script>